# Installing VirtualBox "Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enabled." message

Tags: boot, dual-boot, virtualbox, uefi

I'm trying to install VirtualBox on Ubuntu 18.04 in a dual-boot system with Windows 10 on the other drive partition, my system uses a UEFI partition to boot up.

Upon installation the following message appears, but I can't either accept or create the password that is asking me for.

Part 1
[image: Message part 1]

Part 2
[image: Message part 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have the `Enable EFI` option enabled in the settings for that virtual machine:

[image: VM settings]

You can either change the setting in VirtualBox or you an use the right arrow and enter to select "OK"

Comment: I'd say is the second options since I'm not running anything in a virtualbox, I was actually tying to install virtual box on ubuntu. No I guess my question is, if go select "OK" what are the implications of having a secure boot? and what if I just don't do nothing?

Comment: For a virtual machine there is not much different. These settings exist because some operating systems (MacOS) refuse to boot without secure boot enabled as a security feature or a DRM feature depending on how you look at it. Outside a VM the purpose of secure boot is designed as a way to only boot into a "trusted" source so that a compromised hard drive cannot contain malware. In reality, it doesn't work because 99.9% of people use hard drives without full disk encryption which means malware can still easily execute on such "trusted" drives.